# Why won't the textures in this .obj file show?

Tags: texturing, materials, import

So I downloaded this .stl file http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:442747

Then I converted it to a .obj and .mtl.

I had troubles showing the texture so I searched it up, but all people says is "press ALT+Z", but that just turns the model black, not the texture. It also said the mtl gets imported along with the obj for when I import that.

Comment: check if the object has a material and the textures came in, simply add a light to the scene.

Comment: I don't see any textures used on that model from your link, just a diffuse color. and there is no need to convert to obj/mtl since blender can read stl files..

Comment: Um, sorry, I'm a beginner and I hardly know how to use blender. How can I do this?

Comment: Wait, so there was no textures on that 3d model?

Comment: press ctrl alt U to open the user preferences, under the addon tab search for stl and enable the checkbox

Comment: Alright, so I imported the STL file, but, I also downloaded another .stl file from that site, and all that showed when I pressed ALT+Z was black-ified model.

Comment: Did this have a texture or not? If not, can any of you link me to an STL file which has a texture so I can try to show that?

Comment: I don't think stl file format supports textures, it's a geometry only format. Even if it did when you import mostly only geometry comes in, you have to recreate the materials and textures yourself anyway.

Comment: Um, I'm getting confused now.. Can somebody clarify why I don't get the texture as I import the .stl file? Did it even contain a texture, can someone link me to a file with a texture so I can test it..?

Comment: @JohnSilver From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)): `STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional object without any representation of color, texture or other common CAD model attributes.`

Comment: Oh.. I see, thankyou. So this means I cannot use/download an STL file when I want a texture included.. Thanks guys.

Comment: Hm, how can I get the texture template as a .png file?

Comment: Tell us exactly what you want to do, which model do you want to download and what texture do you want to apply to it?

Comment: I want to download this model and retrieve it's texture. http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:442747 BUT, I can't make the texture appear.

Comment: As poor said, that model has absolutely no texture at all, what do you mean you want to obtain it's texture? It's a flat blue color, which texture did you expect to get? If you want it to appear blue just create a new blue material in Blender.